# how to automate version of azure ARM template

Tags: continuous-integration, versioning, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager

I am building a CI/CD pipeline in VSTS for Azure ARM Template

When I kick off a build in VSTS:

```
- ARM template is generated with a build script I wrote
- ARM template is deployed to Azure
```

I am looking to add a step to increment the version of the ARM template every time I kick off a build.

Does VSTS have any out of the box functionality to increment this version number for me? or do I have to write a script that will read the current version from the arm template, increment it by one, then push the change to GIT? Is there any ways to optimize this process?

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t the official extension can do it, you can do it through PowerShell script, you also can custom build task extension to do it and share to others. [Add a build task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-build-task)

Simple script to update version:

```
param(
[string]$filepath
)
[object]$armObj=Get-Content $filepath|ConvertFrom-Json
$vArray=$armObj.contentVersion.split(".")
$vArray[-1]=[int]$vArray[-1]+1
$armObj.contentVersion=$vArray -join '.'
$armObj | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 |  % { [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Unescape($_) } | set-content $filepath
```